# How do I show my comment count on Blogger blog if I'm using Disqus

Tags: blogger, disqus

Is there a simple way to do this without having an API key? I searched Google for methods and I didn't get a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

First add Disqus's java script before `</body>` tag of Blogger.

```
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//YOUR DISQUS FORUM SHORT NAME HERE.disqus.com/count.js" async=''></script>
```

Replace `YOUR DISQUS FORUM SHORT NAME HERE` with yours.

Then use this code I created bellow to show your comment counter in Blogger any where. This link will create a link as 'Read More' while showing your comment count.

```html
<a expr:data-disqus-url='data:post.canonicalUrl' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-comment-o'/>Comments</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to include the following JavaScript

```
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//shortname.disqus.com/count.js" async=''></script>
```

Replacing `shortname` with your own Disqus Shortname. And to render the comment count for a specific post, you will have to add the following code -

```
<div class="disqus-comment-count" expr:data-disqus-url="data:post.canonicalUrl">Count</div>
```

This will need to be added to the Blogger template only (not widgets or posts)

For more information, refer to https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-adding-comment-count-links-to-your-home-page

Comment: @desbest Could you share the blog URL where you tried this code?

Comment: It's a private blog.

Comment: @desbest Could you share information regarding any error that you saw in the console/inspect element? Also, about the HTML for the comment count, where exactly did you place it inside your template? It will only work if placed inside the Blog1 widget (where the namespace `data:post` is define)